# how to open 1 modal window with 3 different buttons?

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog

I face the problem of opening the same modal window with different buttons. Unfortunately, my knowledge is not enough to solve the problem correctly. I made several scripts for each button, it works like this, but it's not a solution, there should be one code, but how exactly to write it?

An example of the code for 1 button below, I will be grateful for help in supplementing the opening code for the other 2 buttons.

```js
(() => {
    const refs = {
        openBuyModalBtn: document.querySelector("[data-buy-modal-open]"), <sup>open button</sup>
        closeBuyModalBtn: document.querySelector("[data-buy-modal-close]"), <sup>close button</sup>
        buyModal: document.querySelector("[data-buy-modal]"),
        body: document.querySelector("body"),
    };
    refs.openBuyModalBtn.addEventListener("click", toggleModal);
    refs.closeBuyModalBtn.addEventListener("click", toggleModal);
    function toggleModal() {
        refs.buyModal.classList.toggle("is-hidden"); (.is-hidden {opacity: 0; pointer-events: none; transform: scaleX(0);} )
        refs.body.classList.toggle("no-scroll");
    }
})();
```

```html
<button class="buy-now__button" data-buy-modal-2-open type="button">Buy now
  <svg width="32" height="32" class="buy-now__icon">
    <use href="./images/svg/icons.svg#icon-ep-arrow"></use>
  </svg>
</button>
<button class="header-nav__button" data-buy-modal-open type="button">Buy now
  <svg width="32" height="32" class="header-nav__icon">
    <use href="./images/svg/icons.svg#icon-ep-arrow"></use>
  </svg>
</button>

<div class="buy-modal__container is-hidden" data-buy-modal>
  <div class="buy-modal">
    <button class="buy-modal__button buy-modal__button--close" type="button" data-buy-modal-close>
      <svg width="20" height="20">
        <use href="./images/svg/icons.svg#icon-close"></use>
      </svg>
    </button>
    <h2 class="buy-modal__title">Buy now</h2>
    <ul class="buy-modal__picture-list"></ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I TRIED to format your code, but it does not look like it is formattable

Comment: Please tag the actual framework you are using too

Comment: Add the same class to each button, then use an event handler for that class to do the opening.

Comment: There are a lot of ways you can handle this. One has been suggested by DeeGee. The other would be to add an inline eventhandler - for example `<button ... onclick="toggleModal()">`.